# Ecto.Query.CompileError p.league().id() is not a valid query expression

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to write what seems to be a easy Ecto query but I'm getting an error in which I'm not fully understanding.

Basically I'm trying match two ids against each other. here is my current attempt:

#### Query

```
from(p in prediction_scores, where: p.league.id == ^league.id)
```

#### ERROR

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `p.league().id()` is not a valid query expression
(ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.where/3
```

I have a `PredictionScore` that belongs to a `League` and then I have a function that passes in a separate `league`. My query is attempting to match the prediction_score league id against the passed in league id.

Hopefully this is enough information... Let me know if you need to see more I'd be happy to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly do joins:

```
from p in prediction_scores,
  join: l in assoc(p, :league),
  where: l.id == ^league.id
```